Size of prime divisors of $\gcd(a^3 + 2, b^3 + 2)$
Let $n$ be a positive integer. Consider distinct positive integers $a\leq n$, $b\leq n$ and prime $p$ such that $p$ divides $a^3 + 2$ and $b^3 + 2$. Is it true that $p \leq cn^{2-\varepsilon}$ for some constants $c > 0$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, independent of $n$?
Taking the difference $a^3 - b^3 = (a-b)(a^2 + ab + b^2)$, if $p$ divides $a-b$, then it is $O(n)$. If $p\equiv 2 \pmod 3$, then one can show that $p$ must divide $a$ and $b$ and thus $p \leq n$. If $p\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ my idea is to take $s$ with $s^2 \equiv -3 \pmod p$ and write $4(a^2 + ab + b^2) \equiv (2a+b)^2 - s^2b^2 \equiv (2a+b-sb)(2a+b+sb)$, so $p \leq 2a+b+sb$. The terms $2a$ and $b$ have linear size, but my issue is that I cannot seem to bound $sb$, though I feel it should be even $O(n^{3/2})$, perhaps.
However, note that working with the difference $a^2 + ab + b^2$ on its own should not be enough! Indeed, there are (conjecturally) infinitely many primes of the form $n^2 + n + 1$ - the reason why does this not immediately ruin everything is that $a=n$, $b=1$ would require $p$ to divide $1^3 + 2 = 3$.
Any help appreciated!

Reinterpretation:  given $p$, we want to know whether there can ever exist $0 < a, b = O(p^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ such that $a^3+2 \equiv b^3+2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$.  For this to happen, the polynomial $f(x) = x^3+2$ must split completely mod $p$; this happens for $1/6$ of primes by the Chebotarev density theorem.

If the roots $a,b,c$ of $f$ are "equidistributed mod $p$" in a strong enough sense (admittedly a big if!), then two of them are $O(p^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ with probability $\sim p^{2\varepsilon-1}$.  The sum of this over a density-$1/6$ subset of all primes diverges, which suggests heuristically that we can find such $a, b$ infinitely often; i.e. that your bound on $p$ doesn't hold.

@RaviFernando can you elaborate more on how did $p^{1/2 + \varepsilon}$ came up?

Sure:  solving the inequality $p \leq cn^{2-\varepsilon}$ for $n$ gives $n \geq (p/c)^{1/(2-\varepsilon)} = c' p^{1/2 + \varepsilon'}$, for some $c' > 0$ and some $\varepsilon' > 0$ which tends to $0$ as $\varepsilon$ does.  So your question has a negative answer if and only if we can find a  triple $(p, a, b)$ with $0 < a,b \leq n < c' p^{1/2 + \varepsilon'}$, for any given $c', \varepsilon' > 0$.  (Really this says there exist triples with $0 < a,b = o(p^{1/2 + \varepsilon'})$, but little-o and big-O are equivalent because we can shrink $\varepsilon'$ further.)

This is not a proof, but I've added enough numerical explorations to my previous heuristics that I hope you'll forgive me putting it in the "answer" field.
Heuristics (cf. the comments above):
As explained in the comments, your question has a negative answer if and only if for any $\varepsilon > 0$, we can find primes $p$ such that the polynomial $x^3 + 2$ splits completely modulo $p$ and two of the roots satisfy $0 < a, b = O(p^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$.  The splitting part holds for a density-$1/6$ subset of the primes by the Chebotarev density theorem.
As for the size of the roots:  let $p$ be given such that $x^3 + 2$ splits modulo $p$, and let $a, b, c \in \mathbb F_p$ be its roots.  Since $(a, b, c) = (a, a \zeta_3, a \zeta_3^2)$ for a suitable choice of cube root of unity $\zeta_3 \in \mathbb F_p$, we will always have $a + b + c = a(1 + \zeta_3 + \zeta_3^2) = 0 \in \mathbb F_p$.  Besides this condition, it seems reasonable to guess that as $p$ varies, the triples $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb F_p^3$ (up to permutation) are equidistributed mod $p$ in some sense.  Thus we would guess that two out of three roots lie in $(0, p^{1/2 + \varepsilon})$ with probability $3 \left( \frac{p^{1/2 + \varepsilon}}{p} \right)^2 = 3 p^{2\varepsilon - 1}$.  Summing these probabilities for primes $p \leq N$, we would expect the number of such $p$ to be asymptotically
$$
\sum_{p \leq N} \frac{1}{6} \cdot 3 p^{2\varepsilon - 1} \approx \int_2^N \frac{1}{6 \log x} \cdot 3 x^{2\varepsilon - 1} dx = \int_2^N \frac{x^{2\varepsilon - 1}}{2 \log x} dx,
$$
which diverges as $N \to \infty$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$.*  Thus we should expect a negative answer to your question.
*In fact the integral even diverges for $\varepsilon = 0$--although I would definitely be more cautious about drawing conclusions from this.  In particular, the heuristic as stated above would predict that there exist infinitely many triples not only with $a, b = O(p^{1/2})$ (which might be true), but also with $a, b = o(p^{1/2})$ (which is clearly false because $p$ divides $a^2 + ab + b^2$).
Numerics:
I left Mathematica running for a few days (code below) to generate all 32 triples $(p, a, b)$ such that $a \leq 10^7$ and $\log_p(b) < 0.6$; equivalently, $\log_b(p) > \frac{5}{3}$.  The results below seem to me to agree with the prediction that $\limsup (\log_b(p)) = 2$; moreover, if you impose a cutoff size $p \leq N$, the count is in the same ballpark as the integral above (albeit a bit lower than expected).
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
p & a & b & \log_b(p) \\ \hline
74110484143351 & 7708380 & 12016462 & 1.959084 \\ \hline
1892563 & 625 & 2008 & 1.900545 \\ \hline
1342623902881 & 2134291 & 2679548 & 1.886720 \\ \hline
72374798539 & 531717 & 587857 & 1.882315 \\ \hline
44327838193 & 233067 & 615260 & 1.839103 \\ \hline
518098168663 & 224465 & 2475718 & 1.832180 \\ \hline
554677 & 802 & 1443 & 1.818156 \\ \hline
5172463 & 1760 & 4941 & 1.817551 \\ \hline
16082509 & 5566 & 10246 & 1.796847 \\ \hline
378289 & 261 & 1481 & 1.759258 \\ \hline
125885570974879 & 1514114 & 107435543 & 1.755661 \\ \hline
340202345089 & 1010909 & 3810224 & 1.752291 \\ \hline
7092925484149 & 6970778 & 23916635 & 1.741611 \\ \hline
6347497291777 & 23328 & 22663143 & 1.740591 \\ \hline
294418453801 & 3351542 & 4252914 & 1.730202 \\ \hline
26295212521 & 552524 & 1212527 & 1.712756 \\ \hline
1008421 & 704 & 3217 & 1.711682 \\ \hline
1138835073319 & 1575864 & 11160689 & 1.710697 \\ \hline
2307928077913 & 1899526 & 17395789 & 1.707523 \\ \hline
32621435669538019 & 4827609 & 5197889330 & 1.699650 \\ \hline
552511450063 & 5945997 & 8324547 & 1.696782 \\ \hline
4854964152757 & 3735546 & 30876559 & 1.693834 \\ \hline
98782125007 & 1580952 & 3097450 & 1.693833 \\ \hline
3597089873809 & 6038163 & 26079858 & 1.693020 \\ \hline
432933319219 & 4897717 & 8391686 & 1.680629 \\ \hline
23814217978921 & 3599836 & 92396601 & 1.679314 \\ \hline
314799945193 & 4408541 & 7262638 & 1.675831 \\ \hline
23652508145653 & 4934703 & 97229401 & 1.674288 \\ \hline
3465499729 & 241370 & 500626 & 1.673786 \\ \hline
988238743 & 22413 & 237555 & 1.673225 \\ \hline
6782621323 & 190576 & 760524 & 1.671690 \\ \hline
20904242773 & 3973 & 1521286 & 1.669344
\end{array}
Mathematica code used to generate the data above:

For[a = 1, a <= 10000000, a++,
factors := Part[FactorInteger[a^3 + 2], All, 1];
For[i = 1, i <= Length[factors], i++,
p := factors[[i]];
If[Mod[p, 3] == 1 && p >= a^(1/0.6) ,
roots := Roots[x^3 + 2 == 0, x, Modulus -> p];
If[Total[Boole[x <= p^.6 /. {ToRules[roots]}]] >= 2 &&
x == a /. {ToRules[roots]}[[1]],
Print[p, ":  ", roots];
]]]]

